# ¿Por qué el contenido dinámico de owl carousel no se crea?

Tags: javascript, owl, carrusel

Tengo un pequeño problema, estoy creando una vitrina de forma dinámica con un archivo JS, este extrae data de un servicio y lo coloca dentro de un div donde debería cargar owl carousel, el problema es que cuando el JS empieza a incrustar el contenido owl carousel deja de funcionar y no crea los divs y clases necesarios para que owl carousel funcione.

Cuando llega el momento de crear esto, pues no lo crea:

```
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight" style="height: 500px;">
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 14000px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 0ms ease 0s; transform: translate3d(-4200px, 0px, 0px); transform-origin: 4900px center 0px; perspective-origin: 4900px center;">
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 1400px;">

<!-- CONTENIDO DE ITEM -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Aquí mi código:

JS:

```
function drawVit(data) {
    letbox = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (data[i].published == true ) {

            let nombreProductoVit = data[i].name.replace('"'," ");

            let nombreShortProductoVit = nombreProductoVit.split(" ");
            if (nombreShortProductoVit.length > 5){
                nombreShortProductoVit = nombreShortProductoVit.slice(0,5).join(" ");
            } else {
                nombreShortProductoVit = nombreShortProductoVit.join(" ");
            }

            let idProductoVit = data[i].productId;

            let precioProd = 0;
            if (data[i].MASBAJO != undefined) {
                precioProd = data[i].MASBAJO.toFixed().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(,|$))/g, '$1.');
                precioIcon = '<img src="/static/Homy/html/home/images/cmr-icon.svg" width="60" style="display:none;">';
            } else if (data[i].CMR != undefined){
                precioProd = data[i].CMR.toFixed().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(,|$))/g, '$1.');
                precioIcon = '<img src="/static/Homy/html/home/images/cmr-icon.svg" style="width:46px!important; margin:5px; display:initial;">';
            } else {
                precioProd = data[i].NORMAL.toFixed().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(,|$))/g, '$1.');
                precioIcon = '<img src="/static/Homy/html/home/images/cmr-icon.svg" width="60" style="display:none;">';
            }

            let precioNormal = data[i].NORMAL.toFixed().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(,|$))/g, '$1.');
            if (Number(precioNormal) === Number(precioProd)) {
                precioNormal = '<small style="display:none;">Normal '+ '$ ' +precioNormal+'</small>';
            } else {
                precioNormal = '<small>Normal '+ '$ ' +precioNormal+'</small>';
            }
            letbox += '<div class="owl-item">';
            letbox += '<div class="item">'; //<-- Slide
            letbox += '<div class="prod-vitrina">'; // <-- SKUinfo
            letbox += '<div>'; // <-- SKUname
            letbox += '<h3 class="nombre-prod">'+nombreShortProductoVit+'</h3>';
            letbox += '</div>'; // <-- EndSKUname
            letbox += '<div class="precio">'; //<--- Precio
            letbox += '<p class="price-prod">$ ' +precioProd+'</p>';
            letbox += precioNormal;
            letbox += precioIcon;
            letbox += '</div>'; //<--- EndPrecio
            letbox += '<div class="relative">';
            letbox += '<a href="http://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/'+idProductoVit+'/'+getMark(init_ProductVitrina)+'" class="loquiero">&iexcl;LO QUIERO!</a>';
            letbox += '</div>';
            letbox += '</div>'; // <-- EndSKUinfo
            //<img src="http://sodimac.scene7.com/is/image/SodimacCL/des-'+productsVitrina[i].productId+'" style="width:100%"></a>';
            letbox += '<a href="http://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/category/'+init_ProductVitrina[2]+'/'+init_ProductVitrina[3]+'/'+init_ProductVitrina[4]+'" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x500"></a>';
            letbox += '<a href="http://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/category/'+init_ProductVitrina[2]+'/'+init_ProductVitrina[3]+'/'+init_ProductVitrina[4]+'" class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></a>';
            letbox += '</div>'; //<-- EndSlide
            letbox += '</div>';
        }
    }

    $('#owl-demo').append(letbox);

}
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Homy/html/css/owl.carousel.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Homy/html/css/owl.theme.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Homy/html/css/vitrina.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Homy/html/css/home-style.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="vtnHome">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel vitrinaHome"></div>
</div>

<!-- librerias vitrina -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/Homy/html/hprev-h1/js/json-new.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/Homy/html/js/vtnHome.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/Homy/html/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro pero creo que el problema esta en esta línea

```
$('#owl-demo').append(letbox);
```

Deberia ser asi:

```
$(letbox).append('#owl-demo');
```

Entonces básicamente estarías diciendo que el contenido de la variable letbox debería ir Dentro de el id owl-demo, también recuerda ejecutar la función para que se muestre.